# kubectl pod fails to pull down an AWS ECR image

Tags: kubernetes, aws-ecr

**step 1** `sudo $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region xx-xxxx-x)`

**step 2** `curl -LSs https://github.com/fermayo/ecr-k8s-secret/raw/master/gen-secret.sh | bash -`

**step 3** `kubectl describe secret aws-ecr-credentials`

```
Name:         aws-ecr-credentials
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

Data

.dockerconfigjson:  32 bytes
```

**step 4** `kubectl describe pod x`

> Warning  Failed     5s               kubelet, ip-10-46-250-151  Failed to pull image "my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://my-account.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image/latest: no basic auth credentials

Why can't the pod pull down the image?

Comment: Create a deployment.yml and set imagePullSecrets

Comment: How did you deploy this particular pod? Did you use any deployment.yml file

Answer (score 23):

Created a script that pulls the token from AWS-ECR

```sh
ACCOUNT=xxxxxxxxxxxx
REGION=xx-xxxx-x
SECRET_NAME=${REGION}-ecr-registry
EMAIL=email@email.com

#
#

TOKEN=`aws ecr --region=$REGION get-authorization-token --output text \
    --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2`

#
#  Create or replace registry secret
#


kubectl delete secret --ignore-not-found $SECRET_NAME
kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
    --docker-server=https://${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com \
    --docker-username=AWS \
    --docker-password="${TOKEN}" \
    --docker-email="${EMAIL}"
```

and created a Linux cronjob to run this every 10 hours

Comment: worth noting: `--docker-email` is **required** for the kubernetes config to work, even though it is deprecated. it can be set to a bogus value like no@email.com.

Comment: This script is magical! Thank you so much. As an added bonus you can turn this script into a **kubectl plugin** by naming it **kubectl-ecr** and putting it in your path. You can then invoke the script directly from `kubectl` like this  — `kubectl ecr`.

Answer (score 3):

Your Deployment manifest will need to specify that the container registry credentials are in a secret. This is as simple as adding `imagePullSecrets`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
spec:
  containers:
  - image: your-registry/image/name:tag
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: secret-name
```

Comment: Thanks i already have that included in my pod definition. see below

apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata:

  name: dc

  labels:

    name: DomainController

    location: typhoon

spec:

  containers:

  - name: dc

    image: xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/decs-dc:latest

  imagePullSecrets:
  
- name: aws-ecr-credentials

Comment: thanks @rawkode; yours combined with barak's answer seems to be the missing pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I too was banging my head on this and realized it was a region mismatch.  I was getting my token from us-east-2 when the image is located in us-west-2.

Snippet from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html#error-403

> There are times when you may receive an HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error, or the error message no basic auth credentials from the docker push command, even if you have successfully authenticated to Docker using the aws ecr get-login command. The following are some known causes of this issue:
>
> You have authenticated to a different region Authentication requests are tied to specific regions, and cannot be used across regions. For example, if you obtain an authorization token from US West (Oregon), you cannot use it to authenticate against your repositories in US East (N. Virginia). To resolve the issue, ensure that you are using the same region for both authentication and docker push command calls.